# How to completely remove mariaDB so I can reset my root password?

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

so I've installed and set up LAMP - everything worked. I tried to log in to my phpmyadmin as root and it wouldn't let me in (I could log in in mariaDB as root without password). But after I set the password myself it wouldn't let me even in mariaDB (pretty sure I'm typing in correct password).I tried almost everything to reset my root password for mariaDB and nothing worked so I think that my best option is to completely remove mariaDB (and possibly phpmyadmin?) so I can have a fresh start.

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge mariadb`?

Comment: I wish that it would be that easy.. but I get a ton of errors while reinstalling mariaDB and phpmyadmin.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
 libmysqlclient20:amd64
 libdbd-mysql-perl
 mariadb-common
 mariadb-server-core-10.0
 mariadb-client-core-10.0
 mariadb-client-10.0
 dbconfig-mysql
 phpmyadmin

Comment: Personally, I would suggest spending some effort running such services via Docker rather than dumping configuration files and database services all over your local OS

Comment: I'm running this on Virtual Box..

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Docker still works in VirtualBox. My point was that you should not need to concern yourself with `apt-get` and dependency management. https://github.com/phpmyadmin/docker/blob/master/docker-compose.testing.yml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysqld ... --skip-grant-tables
```

then change the password and exit.  No need to reinstall.  Two of many documents:

https://www.tecmint.com/reset-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password/
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password

Comment: merick i have try both method, and both of then none work ing on me.
i use mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2>